Issue with vertical overflow
I have a problem with typewriter animation. When the text arrives to the end of the width, the overflow continues to the right, and I want that it continues below.

This is the CSS of the paragraph:
.aboutMeText{
    font-size: .9rem;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    border-right: 0.15em solid #18bdec;
    animation: typing 15s steps(395) 1s 1 normal both, blink 1s steps(1) infinite;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    overflow-wrap: break-word;
}

@keyframes typing {
    from {
        width: 0;
    }
    to {
        width: 100%;
    }
}

@keyframes blink {
    50% {
        border-color: transparent;
    }
}

I tryed to change and remove some overflow propierties but nothing changed.

I think you are referring to a multiline typing animation:
See this example:


body {
  background: #1a1b1e;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 2rem;
}

#typing-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.typing-text {
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 0;
  animation: typing 2s steps(28, end) forwards;
}

.typing-text:nth-child(1) {
  animation-delay: 0s;
}

.typing-text:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: 0.8s;
}

.typing-text:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: 1.2s;
}

.typing-text:nth-child(4) {
  animation-delay: 2s;
}

@keyframes typing {
  from {
    width: 0;
  }
  to {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
<div id="typing-container">
  <span class="typing-text">Hello</span>
  <span class="typing-text">World!</span>
  <span class="typing-text">I am a </span>
  <span class="typing-text">Programmer.</span>
</div>



